# Find if point is on a line

Tags: postgis

Using PostGIS I would like to filter my database to only the point(s) that are on line(s).

Thinking `ST_Intersects` would be the correct function, but it gave me a strange results I don't understand.

To test I was trying:

```sql
WITH
vertex AS (
    SELECT ST_GeomFromText('POINT(488254.50036713225 6950331.832967171)', 28356) AS geom
),
edge_part AS (
    SELECT ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(488295.7692 6950324.2944,488287.5588999996 6950325.7939,488269.09580000024 6950329.1668,488267.89719999954 6950329.386,488254.50036713225 6950331.832967171)', 28356) AS geom
),
edge AS (
    SELECT ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(488295.7692 6950324.2944,488287.5588999996 6950325.7939,488269.09580000024 6950329.1668,488267.89719999954 6950329.386,488244.95419999957 6950333.5766,488241.9308000002 6950334.1294,488238.2929999996 6950334.7939)', 28356) AS geom
)

SELECT 
    ST_Intersects(vertex.geom, edge.geom) AS vertex_intersects_edge,
    ST_Intersects(vertex.geom, edge_part.geom) AS vertex_intersects_edge_part,
    ST_Intersects(edge.geom, edge_part.geom) AS edge_intersects_edge_part
FROM vertex, edge, edge_part
```

But got results like:

| vertex_intersects_edge | vertex_intersects_edge_part | edge_intersects_edge_part |
| --- | --- | --- |
| false | true | true |

Where I was expecting `vertex_intersects_edge` to be true and I could use that for my filter.

So the question is would this be the correct function for finding if a point is on a line and why is `vertex_intersects_edge` returning false?

Comment: Floating-point equivalence is always an issue. What you really need is a very small `ST_DWithin`

Comment: @Vince, ```ST_DWithin``` seems to be working for what I need, Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per Vince's comment, Using `ST_DWithIn` worked to find a if a point is on a line.

```
WITH
vertex AS (
    SELECT ST_SnapToGrid(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(488254.50036713225 6950331.832967171)', 28356),0.00001) AS geom
),
edge_part AS (
    SELECT ST_SnapToGrid(ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(488295.7692 6950324.2944,488287.5588999996 6950325.7939,488269.09580000024 6950329.1668,488267.89719999954 6950329.386,488254.50036713225 6950331.832967171)', 28356),0.00001) AS geom
),
edge AS (
    SELECT ST_SnapToGrid(ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(488295.7692 6950324.2944,488287.5588999996 6950325.7939,488269.09580000024 6950329.1668,488267.89719999954 6950329.386,488244.95419999957 6950333.5766,488241.9308000002 6950334.1294,488238.2929999996 6950334.7939)', 28356),0.00001) AS geom
)

SELECT 
    ST_DWithin(vertex.geom, edge.geom, 0.001) AS vertex_dwithin_edge,
    ST_DWithin(vertex.geom, edge_part.geom, 0.001) AS vertex_dwithin_edge_part
FROM vertex, edge, edge_part
```

| vertex_dwithin_edge | vertex_dwithin_edge_part |
| --- | --- |
| true | true |